# Incorrect calculations? Excel not performing correct time calculations

Tags: excel

I'm simply trying to find the number of hours between the two dates and times, but excel won't account the date to the number of hours, and only calculates the 'hours' themselves.

[image: image of excel]
[image: image of excel]

Comment: Formatting! Please remove the formatting from cell `B3` and let us know what is there. I'll guess it is `31.7034722222234`.

Comment: I'll bet it's a problem with the format of B1 or B2. When I create a new blank sheet, I get 395.7034722 (i.e., days) in B3 because the default format caused excel to interpret what I was typing in a way that I find counter-intuitive. But that is probably a result of the General format that it was (is) using by default.

Comment: If I remove formatting, it restores to 'General' which is '1.720309954'.

Comment: @Dolvik Did you unaccept my answer?  I thought it had turned green?

Comment: @JLH I have since it hadn't worked for examples like '7/9/17 3:00 PM' > '7/9/17 4:00 PM' which showed 24 hours.

Comment: @Dolvik Please try the formula in my edited answer, which handles dates earlier and later than one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format on cell B3 is wrong.  You may have mistakenly copied the date format from the cells above to B3.

If you set your format to "General" on cell B3 and change the formula to

```
=ABS(B1-B2)*24
```

I think you'll get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Found out another solution by using a custom format,
"[h]:mm:ss" instead of just h:mm:ss